# Generating topological space diagram in Mathematica

Tags: math, graphics, wolfram-mathematica

I have mathematica code to check whether a collection of sets satisfies the definition of a topology, I would now like to programmatically generate diagrams like these: 
[image: topological spaces]

How can this be done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not familiar with your problem but to create diagrams from primitives, that look kind of like the ones you have pasted, you can do this:

start with the "base" case --

```
base = {Circle[{-0.4, 0.4}, 0.1], Disk[{0, .125}, 0.05], 
   Text[Style["1", 24], {0, -0.1}],
   Disk[{0.5, .125}, 0.05], Text[Style["2", 24], {0.5, -0.1}], 
   Disk[{1., .125}, 0.05], Text[Style["3", 24], {1., -0.1}], 
   Circle[{.5, 0}, {.9, .5}]};

Graphics[{base}, ImageSize -> 220]
```

[image]

From here just add elipses to the base case:

```
Graphics[{base, Circle[{0, 0}, {.15, .3}]}, ImageSize -> 220]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{base, Circle[{0, 0}, {.15, .3}], 
  Circle[{0.5, 0}, {.15, .3}], Circle[{0.25, 0}, {.58, .38}]}, 
 ImageSize -> 220]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{base, Circle[{0.5, 0}, {.15, .3}], 
  Circle[{0.25, 0}, {.58, .38}], Circle[{0.75, 0}, {.58, .38}]}, 
 ImageSize -> 220]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{base, Circle[{0.5, 0}, {.15, .3}], 
  Circle[{1, 0}, {.15, .3}], Red, AbsoluteThickness[6], 
  Line[{{-0.4, -0.5}, {1.4, 0.55}}], 
  Line[{{-0.4, 0.55}, {1.4, -0.5}}]}, ImageSize -> 220]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{base, Circle[{0.25, 0}, {.58, .38}], 
  Circle[{0.75, 0}, {.58, .38}], Red, AbsoluteThickness[6], 
  Line[{{-0.4, -0.5}, {1.4, 0.55}}], 
  Line[{{-0.4, 0.55}, {1.4, -0.5}}]}, ImageSize -> 220]
```

[image]

Note that I set Frame->True while tweaking these so I could see the coordinates.

Comment: I am looking to programmatically generate an image for a variable number of points. I think I can generalize this, thank you for your help.

Comment: Friggin sweet job on the diagrams! So spot on that I had to laugh. +1 fo sho.

Comment: Wonderful! Double-clicking your pictures and moving the objects around one can cover cases that are different from @Tobi's examples e.g. the case where the subset `{1,3}` is an element of the list which requires laying points in a triangle.

Answer (score 9):

To complement Mike's cool diagrams, here is a way to check if an arbitrary finite list of lists is a topology, that is, (1) if it contains the empty set, (2) the base set, (3) closed under finite intersections, and (3) closed under union:

```
topologyQ[x_List] :=
  Intersection[x, #] === # & [
    Union[
      {Union @@ x},
      Intersection @@@ Rest@#,
      Union @@@ #
    ] & @ Subsets @ x
  ]
```

Applied to the six examples

```
list1 = {{}, {1, 2, 3}};
list2 = {{}, {1}, {1, 2, 3}};
list3 = {{}, {1}, {2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}};
list4 = {{}, {2}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}};
list5 = {{}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2, 3}};
list6 = {{}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}};
```

like

```
topologyQ /@ {list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6}
```

gives

```
{True, True, True, True, False, False}
```

EDIT 1: For a further refinement of the formulation, note that the operator

```
topoCover := (Union @@ {Union @@@ #, Intersection @@@ Rest@#} &)@Subsets@# &
```

gives the collection obtained by taking all unions and intersections of the elements of a collection of sets. A collection of sets `list` is a topology if it is a fixed point of the operator `topoCover`. So one can define an alternative function to check if `list` is topology:

```
 topologyQ2 := (topoCover@# === #) &
```

If `list` is not a topology, `topoCover` gives the smalles superset of `list` which is a topology. So

```
Complement[topoCover@#,#]&
```

gives the elements to be added to `list` to make it a topology.

One can also consider largest subset(s) of `list` which is a topology and the element(s) to be deleted from `list` to topologize it. This is done by using

```
 maxTopoSubset := (If[{} == #, None, Last@#] &)@(GatherBy[
                     Select[Subsets@#, topologyQ], Length[#] &]) &
```

Applied, for example, to `list6` as

```
 maxTopoSubset@list6
```

we get the two topologies

```
 {{}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}, {{}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}}
```

To get the elements to be removed to get a topology from `list`, one can use

```
 removeToTopologize :=  Table[Complement[#, Part[maxTopoSubset@#, i]], {i, 
                            Length@maxTopoSubset@#}] &
```

Using with `list6` as

```
 removeToTopologize@list6
```

we get

```
 {{{2, 3}}, {{1, 2}}}
```

that is, removing `{2,3}` or `{1,2}` from `list6` gives a topology.

Comment: +1 for being so concise! Here I was all proud of myself for doing it in 9 lines. I'll have to read up on the `Rest` function and the `@@` operator, I haven't seen that before.

Comment: `Rest` is simply leaving the first element and taking the rest of the list. `@@` is short for `Apply`. In this usage `And@@Flatten` is replacing the head `List` with the head `And`. Also `topologyQ /@ {list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6}` is sufficient. @kguler is `Union@Apply[Union,...]` really necessary in the final line? Shouldn't `Apply[Union,...]` do the job?

Comment: @Tobi, thank you. Actually, it took quite a few trial/error iterations to get it working. Had to use `Rest` to get rid of the empty set at the beginning of `Subsets[]` list. Of course, there is still ample room to make it shorter and more elegant.

Comment: @Mike, I get, for example, `{{}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}` from `Apply[Union, Rest@Subsets[list1], 1]`. Need to apply `Union` again to eliminate repeated elements before I check membership.

Comment: ok. I overlooked your use of levelspec. Note that `Apply[Union, Rest@Subsets[list1]]` returns `{{},{1,2,3}}` which is what I was actually thinking of when I made the previous comment.

Comment: @Mike, levelspecs always make me dizzy and I am never sure i got it right; the current case is no exception. I will check again.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I see, Rest[] is like cdr for mathematica.

Comment: Perhaps you should add another argument to your function, indicating the initial set whose topology you want to test. For example if the initial set has 5 elements, none of the example lists would be a topology because 4 and 5 are never mentioned. In other words: topologyQ should be a binary relation between a list of subsets and the initial set. IE. topologyQ[subsets_List,set_]

Comment: @magma, Good point. I thought about adding the inital set as an argument, but decided to use the `Union` of the elements. I think the only change needed is to replace  `MemberQ[x, Union[Flatten@x]]` in the second test with `MemberQ[x, list2]`where list2 is the base set. Need to do some testing to make sure.

Comment: @Tobi, I changed the function, hopefully for the better.  kguler, revert the edit if you don't like it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, "... if I don't like it"? Very elegant and concise. You could have posted as a separate answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I wont be able to give a mathematica specific solution however i might share some insight considering finding all the topologies on a given finite set.
The naive algorithm (the one that checks topological space axioms) runtime would be around $2^2^n$. We will reduce the search space considerably. Key point to realize is that for every preorder on a finite set there is a topology and vice versa.  Given a topology one can create a relation where $x \leq y$ iff $y$ is element of all the open sets which $x$ belongs to. I believe this is called specialization preorder. From a given preorder one can recover the topology by finding the upper sets.
So if we can find all the preorders on a given set, we can recover all the topologies. Finding preorders is considerably easier. A preorder is a binary relation which is transitive and reflexive. So the search space is $2^n^2$.
There are also cool algorithms (Floyd-Warshall ) to find the transitive closure of any given relation. Finding the reflexive closure is also easy (just add the identity matrix to the adjacency matrix represantation)